# How to compute $m$ value from RSA if $phi(n)$ is not relative prime with the $e$?

Tags: rsa, public-key, modular-arithmetic

Here is some information we got :

We know the value of $n$, with size $1043$.

We know the value of $p$ (size $20$) and $q$ (size $1023$) as the factors.

$e = 65537.$

$\varphi(n)$ = $(q-1)(p-1)$

When I calculated $\gcd$ and $\text{modinv}$, I got :

$\gcd(e,\varphi(n)) = 65537$

$modinv(e,\varphi(n)) = 1 $

So we can tell that they are not relatively prime.

So, how to compute the d, and get the value of m?

I'm not that good with math, so I cant understanding well the theory.

so can anyone please make an example implementation or write a clear formula?

Comment: From that, we got :
"GCD(e,phi(n)) = 65537" Could you give more details???

Comment: so we calculate phi(n) from (p-1)*(q-1).


e is 65537,

when i calculated GCD(e,phi(n)) it returns 65537

Comment: Welcome to crypto-SE. If $\gcd(e,\varphi(n))\ne1$, then $e^{-1}\bmod\varphi(n)$ is undefined. Thus some of the calculated stuff is wrong. Hint: use the given that $p$ has size 20 (I guess that's bits) to factor $n$.

Comment: Also such a small $p$ is a massive security risk, even for properly designed RSA.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if we assume that:

- $e$ is prime (65537 is)
- Only one of the primes minus one has $e$ as a factor; for example, $p-1$ is divisible by $e$, but $q-1$ is not.  For this discussion, we'll assume that $p$ is the prime with $p-1 \equiv 0 \bmod e$ (which might happen to be the size 1023 factor for you)
- $p-1$ is not divisible by $e^2$
- That the ciphertext was actually generated by computing $P^e \bmod n$ for some plaintext value $P$.

Then, one way to derive the possible plaintexts is to compute:

$$C^d \cdot L^i \bmod n$$

where:

- $C$ is the ciphertext
- $d = e^{-1} \bmod \lambda / e$
  .  This is well defined, as $\lambda/e$ is an integer which is relatively prime to $e$.
- $L = k^{\lambda/e} \bmod n$, where $k$ is an integer such that $L \ne 1$ (and any such value $L$ works); most values of $k$ work
- $\lambda = (p-1)(q-1)/\gcd(p-1, q-1)$
- $i$ is any integer $0 \le i < e$

Now, if we iterate over the possible values of $i$, this will give $e$ possible values for the plaintext (unless $C$ happens to be a multiple of $p$).  The original plaintext  will be one of these values.  All these values, when raised to the power $e$, will result in the ciphertext, hence we cannot distinguish from the ciphertext which one it is.

Comment: How do things change if (p-1) is divisible by e^2

Comment: @Michael: it gets ugly; considerably more analysis than I felt like doing would need to be applied to get an answer...